# Convert search string from UISearchBar to MK MapView Address

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, uisearchbar

Add a UISearchBar to my MK- MapView and obtain an address on a map using the search string written in the UISearchBar.
Later I have to be able to convert the address indicated on the map in NSString!
Can you help me please? I searched on google but I did not understand anything! Please help me.. I used this project, but when I run the search, the map remains the same point: [project that I used](http://github.com/infolock/eLBeeMKLocalSearch)

Comment: please show your effort for better answers.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: I used this project, but when I run the search, the map remains the same point: https://github.com/digdog/MapKitDragAndDrop

Comment: Please scuse me, the link is this  https://github.com/infolock/eLBeeMKLocalSearch

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can refer following link to find a sample code for map view search a/c to the places.....

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MapSearch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013332

hope this will help you..